# Proof that every natural number is the sum of 9 cubes of natural numbers

Tags: number-theory

What types of proof are there of this result and where can I read about it?

I think that the Hardy-Littlewood circle method can prove that every number is the sum of something like $100000$ cubes, and you can use tables to prove those "small" numbers are all expressible as sums of cubes.. which gives you warings problem but I was more interested in specific proof about the cubes.

*Dickson showed that the only integers requiring nine cubes are $23$ and $239$. Wieferich proved that only $15$ integers require eight cubes: $15, 22, 50, 114, 167, 175, 186, 212, 231, 238, 303, 364, 420, 428,$ and $454$* from [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WaringsProblem.html)

Comment: It is known that every sufficiently large number is a sum of 7 cubes, and conjectured that 4 cubes will do.

Comment: actually I would like to know about cubes of integers too,but I think that problem has less known about it.

Comment: 239 needs 9 cubes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a paper by L E Dickson, Simpler proofs of Waring's Theorem on cubes, with various generalizations, from the Transactions of the American Mathematical Society for 1928, available [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1928-030-01/S0002-9947-1928-1501417-5/S0002-9947-1928-1501417-5.pdf). But you may be disappointed --- "Simpler" doesn't mean "simple".